# Why is tensorflow prediction_step extremely slow when the input features are python primitives instead of tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I spent half an hour debugging on the slowness of the following code snippet

```
import time
feature_values = {'query': ['hello', 'world'], 'ctr': [0.1, 0.2]}

model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)
start = time.time()
output = model.prediction_step(feature_values)
print(time.time() - start)
```

The above took a few minutes to finish. Then I found out that I need to convert the input to tensors first, then it became very fast, as expected.

```
feature_values = {k: tf.constant(v) for k, v in feature_values.items()}
```

My question is why is there such a big latency difference and why the first approach didn't even raise an error?

Answer (score 2):

1. Tensor supports vectorized operations which vanilla lists don't support (as to why see next two points).
2. A Tensor can contain only objects of the same type, while vanilla list can contain all kinds of types of objects in them. When working with Tensor you have to do type checking only once while with lists you have to type check every object.
3. Tensor is stored in a single contiguous block of memory, while vanilla list is fragmented. Hence with Tensor you get less cache misses/pointer dereferencings.

Comment: Thanks. It’s still surprising how slow it is on a single example with only 2 features. Even if everything is computed in python rather than c, it shouldn’t be that slow: the network is just a small DNN.